# Dutch citizenship by naturalization regulations

Tags: resident-permit, citizenship, netherlands, eu-citizens

I currently reside in the Netherlands as a scientific researcher. I have a valid residence card and employment contract. There are some prospects for me to begin a PhD at a large university here. However I would like to make sure that this will not jeopardize my ability to obtain Dutch citizenship in the next few years. In my current understanding and according to the [IND website](https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/Naturalisation.aspx) Naturalization requires that one reside in the Netherlands for an uninterrupted period of at least 5 years.

However this only encompasses individuals with a valid residence permit for "non-temporary purposes of stay...at the time of the naturalization ceremony". The definition of "temporary" versus "non-temporary" is given by [this link](https://ind.nl/en/Pages/temporary-and-non-temporary-purposes-of-stay.aspx).

The link lists "Study" as a "Temporary" purpose of stay. I therefore have two questions:

- Does a fully funded, 5-year technical PhD count as mere "study"? May I use 5 years as a PhD to justify citizenship?
- If not, can an individual still apply for citizenship after the end of the PhD? Say for example I finished my PhD in 4 years and then secured a job, continuing to live in the Netherlands for another year under a regular employment contract. Would the years spent as a PhD candidate accrue and count as regular residency?

Thanks and look forward to your answers.

Comment: I don't think PhD is a studying. You are earning payment so I consider it is a job here. But to make sure I would just call IND. In general, they are nice people.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question ?

Comment: No because I was not accepted for the position. The question is irrelevant to me now. Perhaps it can be useful for others though if an answer is found

Comment: @user32882 It would certainly be helpful to me :)

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have an answer... But I will keep the question in case someone else has a better answer

Comment: Hi, I spoke with the immigration office a couple of months ago and it counts since I had the same question as yours. Generally, it's better to contact the Foreign Affairs Office, but the first step is the PR, not the Citizenship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert, but I think PhD study counts towards residence permit. Because you work as a "scientific researcher", which is a not temporary purpose of stay. Here is [the link](https://ind.nl/en/work/Pages/Scientific-researcher.aspx) to IND.

Here is [the link](https://ind.nl/en/Pages/temporary-and-non-temporary-purposes-of-stay.aspx) specifying what temporary and non-temporary purposes of stay are.

Comment: In the second link you provided, under the temporary purposes,there is  "With a residence permit for a temporary purpose", and in the list "study", so I'm not sure how does Phd does not sound as temporary. ı mean I hope I'm wrong, but I don't see you logic in here.

Comment: Indeed there is an apparent contradiction in @YKY's answer. If PhD study counts towards a residence permit then why is it listed as *temporary* purpose of stay in the link..?